# SharePoint GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl /Files API not returning list of files as expected

Tags: file, api, sharepoint

I'm new to SharePoint and I'm having trouble with a few of the simple examples I've found and I'm not sure if there's a permission I don't have correct or if I'm not understanding this properly.

when I use a browser to access my URL:

```
https://mysite.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/SCF/Shared%20Documents/FY%202014%20Memos')
```

part of the return xml says there are 87 items `<d:ItemCount m:type="Edm.Int32">87</d:ItemCount>`, which does correctly correlate to the number of files inside this folder.

Here's where I get confused.  When I use the following to show the contents of the folder, I don't get any of the file information listed in the result xml like I would expect:

```
https://mysite.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/SCF/Shared%20Documents/FY%202014%20Memos')/Files
```

I've also tried the following to get specific file info, but I get a file not found message:

```
https://mysite.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/SCF/Shared%20Documents/FY%202014%20Memos/096.pdf')
```

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 12):

This behavior occurs since the incorrect context of web for [SP.Web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245434%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is specified in REST query:

```
https://[server]/[web]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/[web]/[library]/[folder]')
                   |
                   web site from which Folder/Files are retrieved
```

Assume the following site structure:

```
/ News web (root)
    |
    Archive sub web
       |
        Documents library
            |
            2008 Folder
```

Then the following REST query:

```
https://[server]/archive/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/archive/Documents/2008')/Files
```

or

```
https://[server]/archive/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents/2008')/Files
```

will return the files located in `2008` folder of `Documents` library under `Archive` sub site.

Answer (score 0):

believe it or not, my problem was sending the parameter with double quote instead of single quote

good:

```
https://[server]/[web]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/[web]/[library]/[folder]')
```

bad:

```
https://[server]/[web]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/[web]/[library]/[folder]")
```